# Indicator variable question -- expected value of elevator stops

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

A building has $n$ floors, labeled $1, 2, \ldots n.$ At the first floor, $k$ people enter the elevator, which is going up and is empty before they enter. Independently, each decides which of floors $2, 3, \ldots n$ to go to and presses that button (unless someone has already pressed it).

(a) Assume for this part that only the probabilities for floors $2, 3, \ldots n$ are equal. Find the expected number of stops the elevator makes on floors $2, 3, \ldots n.$

(b) Generalize (a) to the case that floors $2, 3, \ldots n$ have probabilities $p_2, \ldots p_n$; you can leave your answer as a finite sum.

*(Introduction to Probability  by Blitzstein and Hwang, Chapter 4 #43)*

I first came up with a solution and then thought it didn't make intuitive sense. After that, I came up with a different solution which makes more sense to me. However, I am struggling to precisely articulate why it is that my first solution doesn't work. I would also like it if someone could please confirm to me that the second one is correct.

Solution that I believe is incorrect:

(a) Let $X$ be the random variable for the number of stops that the elevator makes on the $j^{th}$ floor and let $I_i$ be the indicator variable such that $I_i = 1$ means that the $i^{th}$ person wants to press the $j^{th}$ floor and $I_i = 0$ means that the $i^{th}$ person does not want to press the $j^{th}$ floor. Then we have

$$X = I_1 + I_2 \ldots I_k$$

and hence

$$E[X] = E[I_1 + I_2 + \ldots I_k] = E[I_1] + E[I_2] + \ldots E[I_k].$$

By the fundamental bridge we find that $E[I_i] = P( \text{the ith person wants to hit floor j}) = \frac{1}{n-1}$, and so it follows that $E[X] = \frac{k}{n-1}$. Then since the expected value is the same for each of the $n-1$ floors, the total amount of distinct floors is $n-1 \left( \frac{k}{n-1} \right) = k.$ This doesn't make intuitive sense to me because it technically shouldn't be expected that all $k$ people will select different floors!

(b) Uses same reasoning to find $k \left( \displaystyle \sum_{i = 2}^n p_i \right)$

Solution that I think is correct:

Let $X$ be the random variable for the total amount of stops and let $I_k$ be the indicator variable such that $I_k = 1$ if someone stopped at the $k^{th}$ floor and $I_k = 0$ if someone did not stop at the $k^{th}$ floor. Then

$$X = I_2 + I_3 + \ldots + I_n,$$

and it follows again that

$$E[X] = E[I_2 + I_3 + \ldots + I_n] = E[I_2] + E[I_3] + \ldots + E[I_n].$$

Then note that $E[I_j] = P( \text{at least someone hit the jth button}) = 1 - \left( \frac{n-2}{n-1} \right)^k$ (i.e. 1 minus the probability nobody hit it), and it hence follows that $E[X] = (n-1) \left( 1 - \left( \frac{n-2}{n-1} \right)^k \right).$

(b) We use the same reasoning except we identify that $E[I_j] = P( \text{ at least someone hit the jth button}) = 1 - (1 - p_j)^k$ (i.e. 1 minute the probability nobody hits it), and it follows from there that

$$E[X] = \displaystyle \sum_{j = 2}^n 1 - (1 - p_j)^k = n-1  - \left( \displaystyle \sum_{j = 2}^n (1 - p_j)^k \right)$$

Comment: Looks good to me